# not getting update value of variable in ionic

Tags: ionic3

This is my code in provider locationtracker.ts

```
 watch: any;
lat: number=0;
lng: number=0;

this.watch = this.geolocation.watchPosition().filter((p) => p.coords !== undefined).subscribe(position => {
  this.lat = position.coords.latitude;
  this.lng = position.coords.longitude;
  this.msg = "front"+position.coords.latitude;
  this.id = 2;
  console.log(this.lat);
  this.showNotification();
  console.log(this.lng);
});
```

This is my code for getting the value of lat lng.

```
this.lat = this.locationTracker.returnLat();
this.lng = this.locationTracker.returnLng();
```

But I am getting only 0 value in lat lng, not the updated value.

Comment: so where do you initialize this.watch? please share full code of your component in question